# Division vs. multiplication by reciprocal in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm working with matrices in R, and noticed something strange:

```
set.seed(1234)
m <- replicate(10, rnorm(20))
all(m / 7 == m * (1/7)) #FALSE
```

Why is that ? Shouldn't the multiplication by the reciprocal be equivalent to normal division ?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the imprecision resulting from [floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). You should find that the values are very close.